# SQL query - Sum of total refund amount

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the total refund amount in the last 365 days. However, This return the total refund amount (not last 365 days only). What should be the right way to do this?

```
     SELECT  sum(a.total_amount) AS TotalRefund365Days
     from  [dbo].[UserPurchase] a
           inner join [dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds] b 
                   on a.user_purchase_id = b.user_purchase_id
     where a.is_refunded = 1 AND b.DateCreated >  (getdate() - 365)
```

**[dbo].[UserPurchase]**
[image: [dbo].[UserPurchase]]

**[dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds]**
[image: [dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds]]

> Note: *([dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds].Amount* is total purchase quantity which is not required)

Comment: Provide a sample as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (textual, code-formatted) which reproduces the issue.

Comment: You can use https://dbfiddle.uk/ as a way to provide the details asked for by @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is what David Browne pointed out in your other post regarding this, which is your relationship between the `dbo.UserPurchase` and `dbo.UserPurchaseRefunds` is one-to-many. This results in your current query are *double counting* the `Total_Amount`.

What you want to do is use a CTE or subquery to *de-dupe* the redundant rows first, then aggregate the remaining rows, like so:

```
SELECT SUM(RefundedAmounts.total_amount) AS TotalRefund365Days
FROM
(
    SELECT a.total_amount
    FROM dbo.UserPurchase a
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserPurchaseRefunds b 
        ON a.user_purchase_id = b.user_purchase_id
    WHERE a.is_refunded = 1 
        AND b.DateCreated >  (GETDATE() - 365)
    GROUP BY a.user_purchase_id, a.total_amount
) AS RefundedAmounts
```